# Choosing random lines with replacement from an XY file

Tags: bash, shell, random, awk, text-processing

I have an XY file with over 40000 unique lines of floating numbers. I want to use bootstrap resampling on this file. Bootstrap resampling works as follows: it resamples N random lines (N is the number of the input file)with replacement from the input file. This means the new data set(output) has the same number of lines as the first file and the new dataset can contain some lines multiple times and might not contain some of the original lines at all. I tried shuffling lines using

```
shuf -n N input > output
```

and

```
sort -R input | head -n N > output
```

, but it seems they don’t implement the replacement.

It is deeply appreciated if somebody could introduce a way to do this using AWK and Shell.

Comment: You want to Take `N` random records from input file and in output file count should be same as input file ?

Comment: Can you explain your request a bit better. It is compleltely unclear what you want to do. The way I understand this is that you want to extract n lines from your file (**Q1** can these lines contain repetitions?), shuffle them, and replace these _n_ lines with the new ordering. (**Q2** how can this have duplicates?)

Comment: @DigvijayS The number of output lines should be the same as the first file.

Comment: @kvantour The number of lines for output should be similar with the input. Bootstrap samples randomly with replacement from the input file. So, for each draw, all lines of the input file (even previously selected lines for the output) have the same possibility to be chosen. In other words, each time for selecting each line, we randomly choose from the original input file. The output can have repetitive lines from the input or may have not any lines from the input. I hope this could clarify a little bit more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are after is the following:

Assume you have an input file `input` with the following content:

```
$ seq 10 > input
```

Then you can get a new randomised file with the same lines and possible repetitions as following:

```
$ shuf -rn $(wc -l input) input
7
2
9
3
1
7
4
8
7
10
```

Here we use the `-r` flag to allow for repetitions.

Comment: Thanks so much. This works very well. It changes 44000 lines of unique data into around 28000 unique lines. I am just curious is there any way to control the number of repetitive lines in the output?

Comment: If you want a maximum of n repetitions, you have to do it differently: `awk -v n=10 '{for(i=1;i<=10;++i) print}' input | shuf -n $(wc -l input)`. What you do is print each line maximum `n` times and then shuf in it without repetitions.